# Vim: How to Install Airline?

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I'm just getting started with Vim. It's a fun experience, but I've found it to be kind of overwhelming. I'm trying to get this plugin installed, **vim-airline**, but I'm having a lot of trouble. The **Installation** section on the [Github page](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) simply states:

> copy all of the files into your ~/.vim directory

Presumably, this means download the .zip, extract it, and copy all of those files into ~/.vim/. I did this, but Vim just starts up like normal, and running `:help airline` just gives:

> Sorry, no help for airline

I assume that this means it isn't getting installed. Also, the statusbar remains the same. I'm new to Vim and would really like to get this working. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I also tried putting the files into /usr/share/vim/vim73/. No dice.

**EDIT 2:** I ran `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` and now the help-page displays when I type `:help airline`, but I'm still not getting the plugin itself (the status bar). Vim looks the same, but it can now display the help page.

Comment: Please accept answer to the one that points out that `Add set laststatus=2 to your vimrc.` needs to be set.

Answer (score 26):

Check the project's [FAQ](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/wiki/FAQ).

> **vim-airline doesn't appear until I create a new split**
>
> Add `set laststatus=2` to your vimrc.

Inside vim, do `:h laststatus` to understand why this is needed. If you want to know in the future if a plugin is being "loaded" or not, check `:scriptnames`.

Answer (score 6):

I installed airline using install instructions from https://github.com/bling/vim-airline

They recommended several package managers - I picked the first one:

**Pathogen**

> git clone https://github.com/bling/vim-airline ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline

I got *:help airline* to work with this command:

> :helptags ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/doc

Like you, now the help-page displays when I type *:help airline*.

Answer (score 5):

When you download [the latest version of vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/archive/master.zip) as `.zip` and unzip it to a temporary directory, you get a `vim-airline-master` directory in the temp directory. Inside `vim-airline-master` you'll find `autoload`, `doc` and `plugin` directories. You should either

- copy these three directories to your `~/.vim/` *if they don't yet exist* (don't overwrite existing directories with same names!) or
- copy the contents of the aforementioned three directories to existing directories under `~/.vim/`

However, as a side note, I strongly suggest looking into [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) as I've found it the most trouble-free way to play with Vim plugins.

Comment: Yes, I tried copying the three directories, `autoload`, `doc`, and `plugin` into `~/.vim/` using `cp -r`. Don't worry, `cp -r` will not overwrite existing directories -- it will simply "combine" them. In fact, I didn't even have a `~/.vim/` directory before I tried this. As for Pathogen, I couldn't get that installed either! It seems whatever plugin I try to install is ignored. Never used Vim before, so I'm not really sure what to do...

Comment: pathogen is trivial to install, all you need to do is follow instructions from pathogen.vim: copy that file to ~/.vim/autoload and add `call pathogen#infect()` to ~/.vimrc. Then all plugins will be subdirectories of ~/.vim/bundle. Do you have a .vimrc file?

Answer (score 2):

Those manual installation instructions assume a lot -- I would say they're just wrong. The plugin files should actually be copied into various subdirectories of your `~/.vim` directory.

I downloaded the zip file from its [Vim scripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4661) page and took a look.

The `doc/airline.txt` file goes into your `~/.vim/doc` subdirectory. The `plugin/airline.vim` file goes into your `~/.vim/plugin` subdirectory. The `autoload/airline.vim` file goes into your `~/.vim/autoload` directory as does the `autoload/airline` directory and all its contents.

This is one of those more complicated plugins that should probably be installed using a plugin manager, but I wouldn't worry about that until you get a little more experience with Vim.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; however, this is how I already have things set up. The directories that I downloaded from the Airline site -- `doc`, `autoload`, and `plugin` (and the files they contain) have been merged with the respective directories within `~/.vim/`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install vim-airline for gvim on Windows platform. But you should be able to follow the same process for linux based OS as well and install it without any problem.

**NOTE:** This installation procedure is manual.

Do the following steps to install vim-airline:

1. Click on download zip (https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) and unzip it.
2. **For Windows Users:**

   Copy all the contents in vim-airline-master and paste it into **$HOME\vimfiles** folder. If vimfiles folder is not present then create a new folder named vimfiles in your home folder.

   you can find your home folder by running the command `:echo $HOME` in vim.

   **For Linux Users:**

   Copy all the contents in vim-airline-master and paste it into **$HOME/.vim**
   directory using command `cp -r`.
3. Now Open your .vimrc file by running the command `:edit $HOME/.vimrc`.
   Add the following line into your .vimrc file.

   `set laststatus=2`

   **Reason:** The default setting of 'laststatus' is for the statusline to not appear until a split is created. If you want it to appear all the time, add the following to your vimrc: set laststatus=2

   For more details run the command `:help laststatus` in vim.
4. Finally To add help for vim-airline run the following command in vim.

   **For Windows Users:**

   ```
   :helptags $HOME\vimfiles\doc
   ```

   **For Linux User:**

   ```
   :helptags $HOME/.vim/doc
   ```
5. Run `:help airline` in vim for more help and configurations.

   Enjoy the colorful line!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the files were not copied in the right place.

Under `.vim` directory, `plugin`, `doc` and `autoload` directories should go. I suspect `vim-airline-master` directory went under `.vim` directory and that is why the plugin is not getting set up.

Comment: (kindly see the comment I posted to your other answer)

Answer (score 1):

Even once you have a plugin properly installed, you may need to do this to make its help file accessible:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

After that, running "`:help airline`" should work and it should tell you how to properly set it up for use in your Vim environment.

Comment: Okay, cool. I'm on my Mac now (OS X 10.4.11) and I tried the install again, and ran this `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` command, which **did** get the help screen for airline to display! :) However, I don't get the plugin itself -- the status bar. Do I have to "activate" it or something?

Comment: It should activate automatically everything that is placed in `autoload` directory.

Comment: But... it's not?

Comment: MunkyCheez: Do any of AirLine's scripts show up in the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: Yes, they do. Here's the output of `:scriptnames`: http://pastebin.com/JXuGFedu

Comment: Then they _are_ being sourced, and it comes down to proper usage.  Does the help file tell you how to run it?

Comment: Great, I read some of the help file and now I've got it running. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and install a plugin manager like [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).

It makes handling plugins a *lot* easier.

Once you have pathogen set up, installing airline is simple. If you have `git`:

```
git clone https://github.com/bling/vim-airline ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline
```

Without git you have to download the zipfile `vim-airline-master.zip`. Then:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
unzip ~/vim-airline-master.zip
mv vim-airline-master vim-airline
```

Comment: As much as I'd like to simplify things and (eventually) get Pathogen set up, I was unsuccessful in my endeavors of doing so. I'd rather work on one issue at a time, if you know what I mean. I'll work on Pathogen again once I can get Airline installed.

Comment: I fully inderstand, but with all due respect I suggest that getting pathogen to work should be the first priority because it will make subequent plugins much easier. You can find the install instructions on [pathogen's github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen). The only detail missing is that `execute pathogen#infect()` should be the _first_ command in your `~/.vimrc`.